# C++ unsequenced modifications for iterators

Tags: c++, undefined-behavior, sequence-points

I have next code in one unit test for iterators:

```
EXPECT_TRUE(++it != it++);
```

Where `it` respects std iterator requirements.

As far as I know 2 modifications of the same variable in the same sequence point is undefined behavior(`!=` is not sequence point).

Considering both `operator++` versions are functions that have a `return` statement(sequence point) does undefined behavior apply in these case? If no, why I received `"Multiple unsequenced modifications to it"` warning on Apple LLVM 5.0 compiler?

What happens when the functions are inlined(most probably they will be!)?

Comment: and it happend again...

Answer (score 4):

First, in some cases, the "iterator" may be just a `typedef` to
a pointer, so there will be no sequence points (or in C++11, the
operations won't be sequenced) in the expression, and you have
undefined behavior.

*If* the `++` operator is overloaded with a function, you do
have a sequence pointer both when the function is called, and
when it returns.  On the other hand, the order in which the
functions are called is still unspecified, so the results of the
comparison are unspecified.

Answer (score 1):

Even though the behavior is not undefined if the two operators are function calls, they are evaluated in unspecified order: the compiler is free to first evaluate `++it` and then `it++` or the other way around. The results are likely different. The test assumes a left to right order but that isn't guaranteed.

Whether the functions are inlined doesn't matter: inlining is an optimization, i.e., it isn't allowed to change the meaning of well-defined programs. Of course, when inlining things the compiler may end up making different choices with respect to evaluation order. However, the compiler is free to make a different choice each time it is invoked anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The point is if it happens in teh same sequence... A sequqnece point jsut ends the sequence, so what you are doing is exactly that what you already said, ou did a modification of the same variable within the same invokation which isn't cut by a sequence point.